# Event numericupdown_BackColorChanged don't trigger

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, numericupdown, backcolor

I want to program an app where the user can enter a number in a NumericUpDown Control. There are some conditions to the number (e.g. range) that are determined in run time. To give feedback to the user I changed BackColor of NumericUpDown to red when at least one condition is not met. So far it works as i expect it to do.

Now i wanted to add a ToolTip to NumericUpDown to explain why the number was "wrong". When I use the event NumericUpDown_BackColorChanged to adjust the text, the event just won't "trigger". Why is that?

I guess it has to do with the composite character of NumericUpDown as [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) has stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701789/numericupdown-background-colour-change-for-disabled-element) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631788/numericupdown-backcolor-not-working-as-expected). But I am not sure. TY for the help in advance.

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numericUpDown1.Value == 42)
        {
            numericUpDown1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            numericUpDown1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        }
    }

private void numericUpDown1_BackColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //something epic should happen
        //but somehow my program never reaches these lines :(
    }
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to make sure the code enters the first event and doesn't enter the second? Or is it a conclusion by observation of result?

Comment: Yes I have set a breakpoint! And the color changed RED. Breakpoint wasn't reached.

Comment: I meant no offense, I just wanted to make sure because I see no reason the event wouldn't be triggered, regardless of the fact that it's a composite control.

Comment: Check your property windows of NumericUpDown contol. make the Enter property of Event to numericUpDown1_ValueChanged..

Comment: @Rotem no offence taken.

Comment: @kovilpattiCsharper 1st Enter is a event not a property. 2nd what should that help? (for couriosity i did and as i expect it didn't change anything)

Comment: @MartinHoratschek: sorry for misleading, for me it worked well and when I watch through the property windows, I found this change, just suggested it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've confirmed that the `NumericUpDown.BackColor` property setter indeed does not call `OnBackColorChanged` (in .NET 4.0 at least).

I assume this happens because the `BackColor` property has been overriden in `UpDownBase` to also set the `BackColor` of the composited controls inside `NumericUpDown` and maybe someone forgot to call the base implementation (I'd love to hear from some of the WinForms gurus here).

What you can do is create a `FixedNumericUpDown` control that inherits from `NumericUpDown` and overrides the `BackColor` property as such:

```
public Color BackColor
{
    override set
    {
        base.BackColor = value;
        OnBackColorChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: TY. So basicly it's a bug in the .NET framework? If so I can write a bug report.

Comment: I'd hate to be the boy that cries bug, but it really does seem like it.

Comment: The Bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775586/set-numericupdown-backcolor-dont-trigger-the-event-backcolorchanged

Comment: I'd love to hear what they have to say about it.

Comment: Status of the Bug-Report changed do "Resolved". Resolution set to "Won't Fix"! I guess Windows Forms are at END OF LIFE.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:** You can do this by add a [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) in your by drag and drop from toolbox.

Replace your code as below:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        errorProvider1.Clear();

        if (numericUpDown1.Value == 42)
        {
            numericUpDown1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            errorProvider1.SetError(numericUpDown1, "Select another number");
        }
        else
        {
            numericUpDown1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ty for the input. I will consider this. still the point is that there are some external events that changes the conditions of the number (i.e. that is not the only part in the program that changes the color in red.) Now I am looking for a simple solution that catches every instance where I changed the color in red.

Comment: wherever you are writing  numericUpDown1.BackColor = Color.Red; you can also write errorProvider1.SetError(numericUpDown1, "Select another number");

Comment: @Arshad While your solution works, it's a workaround, not a solution. The interesting question here is why isn't the event triggering, not what can be done in this particular case to show an error.

Comment: @Arshad Obviously I could do that. The point is that i already wrote that part and don't want to go over it all again just to repeat a single line several times (DRY!).